# Using Bootstrap method to calculate p-value in hypothesis testing for single population variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, bootstrap

As per my study material, there is no default function in R to conduct hypothesis test for single population variance. So, I have written the following code in R to calculate p-value under (i) Assuming theoretical distribution, as well as (ii) Bootstrap approach. However, as seen below, there is huge difference in p-values under both - 0.1244934 under (i) and 0.02545 under (ii), also clearly seen in comparative graphs. Am I doing it correctly?

## Single Variance Test -

weight

[Output]  242  290  340  363  430  450  500  390  450  500  475  500  500  340  600  600  700  700  610  650  575  685  620  680  700  725 720  714  850 1000  920  955  925  975  950

qqnorm(weight)

qqline(weight)

[image: QQ-Plot]

boxplot(weight)

[image: Boxplot]

var(weight)

[Output] 43767.03

#H0 : var0=60000

#H1 : var0<60000

> ## Using theoretical distribution

tsv<-(NROW(weight)-1)*var(weight)/60000

tsv

[Output] 24.80132

pv.th<-pchisq(tsv,NROW(weight)-1)

pv.th

[Output] 0.1244934

> ## Using Bootstrap approach

var.est<-vector()

n<-1:100000

for(i in n){x<-sample(weight,NROW(weight),replace = TRUE);var.est[i]<-60000+(var(x)-var(weight))}

hist(var.est)

pv.emp<-length(var.est[var.est<=var(weight)])/length(var.est)

pv.emp

[Output] 0.02545

> ## Comparative graphs

trans<-var.est*(NROW(weight)-1)/60000

hist(trans,probability = TRUE,xlim = c(0,70))

curve(dchisq(x,df=NROW(weight)-1),add = TRUE,lwd=2,col="red")

pv.th

[Output] 0.1244934

length(trans[trans<=tsv])/length(trans)

[Output] 0.02545

pv.emp

[Output] 0.02545

[image: Comparative graphs]

Comment: [These notes](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~rgould/110as02/bshypothesis.pdf) seem relevant for your bootstrap test.

Answer (score 0):

Minitab statistical software has a procedure for
testing a single variance. Assuming that $n = 35$ [deduced from what you show],
here are relevant parts of the output from a recent release of Minitab. The P-value $0.124$ agrees with
your theoretical result.

```
 Test and CI for One Variance 

 Method

 Null hypothesis         σ-squared = 60000
 Alternative hypothesis  σ-squared < 60000

 The chi-square method is only for 
 the normal distribution.

 Statistics

  N  StDev  Variance
 35    209     43765

 95% One-Sided Confidence Interval

             Upper
             Bound
               for   Upper Bound
 Method      StDev  for Variance
 Chi-Square    262         68684

 Test
                  Test
 Method      Statistic  DF  P-Value
 Chi-Square      24.80  34    0.124
```

So it seems you need to look for trouble in your
bootstrap method. I can't check your bootstrap because (a) you
don't explain your method [except via undocumented code] and (b) I don't have access
to your data.

However, I wonder whether you have looked at
your data to see whether they are consistent
with a random sample from a normal distribution. If they are not, then there is no reason to expect any bootstrap procedure to match normal-based theoretical results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added sample data "weight", its Normal Q-Q Plot and Boxplot. Please check. Also, I don't know what you mean by method (my study material doesn't have any, it simply asks to carry out hypothesis test by Bootstrap method). I will be thankful if you can give me link to the resources explaining different methods of Bootstrap.

Comment: Suggested a link in my Comment just below your Q. Mainly process-oriented, but rationales given for some steps. Google 'bootstrap testing' and similar phrases for more. Try to find lecture notes from major universities. (Any idiot with an Internet connection can claim to be a bootstrapping guru, and there are links to illustrate that.) // I have to say I have a personal preference to do bootstrapping for CIs and to do testing via permutation tests. Some good links on permutation tests also. If interested, Google `eudey permutation test education` for one of them.

Comment: I have now installed "wBoot" package in R. However, it is calculating p-value differently and I have verified their method by calculating it separately myself by running code numerous times. As per the definition, we calculate p-value as prob of obtaining the "observed or more extreme value", given Null Hypothesis is true. This "wBoot" package is calculating p-value in case of bootstrap approach as prob of obtaining "null hypothesis or more extreme value", given the bootstrap sampling distribution. Is this approach correct?

Comment: There many styles of bootstraps and I am not sure the one you are using in R is exactly the same as my very simple version. You don't say how much different your result is. Also, the number of re-samples can make a difference in the results. Finally, because bootstrapping involves simulation, even the same method with the same number of re-samples may give slightly different  results on different runs.